# scaling app to bigger screens

Tags: android

I made a simple app with relative layout and dips. the problem is that on larger screens it just takes up a tiny part of the screen. is there a way to make it just one size and somhow scale to larger screens keping the layout intact?

Comment: if you specify the dips, you are setting the size.  if someone has a screen with more dips, what would you expect it to do?  If you want it to scale to larger (and smaller screens) don't hardcode dips.  and post your layout and maybe someone could suggest alternatives

Comment: I thought as much. I was hoping there was a combination you can use in the supports-screens tag to get this, as there are videos of motorola xoom reviews showing old app running full screen with the ui seemingly intact.

Comment: anything that is using `fill_parent` seems to work fine like that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new folder `layout-large` and one `layout-normal`.

Copy your xml files that have fixed sizes to both folders, and adapt the size of the fixed-size `View`s to the larger screens (in layout-large). It will be approximately 50% larger. You can fine tune the sizes in the emulator. I found it easy to have two emulator instances, one with a normal screen and one with a large one so I can tweak the sizes and see the results in both layouts.

Also, consider that many of the larger screens retain the same resolution as the bigger phones (thus, having a much reduced dpi), so you may want to scale down images and copy them to a `drawable-mdpi` folder, keeping the originals in a `drawable-hdpi` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Android SDK section on Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

This goes over what the best practices are for how to do this.

Comment: The dev guide doesn't talk about how existing apps scale to larger screens keeping the ui intact. May not be the best practice way, but its what I need to do.

Comment: Yeah the SDK doesn't go into a lot of detail on that, its more focused on how to get your graphics to scale. What you could do is create multiple layouts. For small and medium screen just use your existing layout. For large and xlarge create new layouts that contain additional content so the screen inst so sparse or choose large text images etc. In that doc I sent you earlier is a link to a reference document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources see this for details on how to do it look at the Screen size qualifier name

Comment: Supporting Multiple Screens doc glosses over some important points> Basically devices will scale dip/dp (and sp) sized resources depending on what density "bucket" they fall into and not on the actual density of the screen. So 240,260, 270, 300 dpi will all get scaled as if they are 240. This creates massive problems.